# Tokenizing autocomplete jquery plugin not working with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I am using the [autocomplete plugin](http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/) but for some reason it is not getting to the controller when I start typing in the text box.

Has anyone used this? or worked with this? or got a working example? I've tried changing the url to `/Referral/Get` but still does not work

```
$("#uxSearch").tokenInput("../Referral/Get",
        {
            hintText: "Type in something",
            noResultsText: "No Results",
            searchingText: "Searching",
            classes: {
                tokenList: "token-input-list-facebook",
                token: "token-input-token-facebook",
                tokenDelete: "token-input-delete-token-facebook",
                selectedToken: "token-input-selected-token-facebook",
                highlightedToken: "token-input-highlighted-token-facebook",
                dropdown: "token-input-dropdown-facebook",
                dropdownItem: "token-input-dropdown-item-facebook",
                dropdownItem2: "token-input-dropdown-item2-facebook",
                selectedDropdownItem: "token-input-selected-dropdown-item-facebook",
                inputToken: "token-input-input-token-facebook"
            }
        });
```

Comment: What does the signature of your controller look like? Can you call it normally as a URL (i.e. what happens if you put `/Referral/Get/query` in your browser address bar)?

Comment: thanks. That showed I had an ambigous action and led me on to getting it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might show us your global.asax.cs routes. Avoid using ../ in relative URLs with ASP.NET MVC. Rather use it like this with a helper method:

```
$("#Products").focus().autocomplete('<%=Url.Action("GetProducts", "Product") %>', { ...
```

(the above is from my autocomplete request)

As Zhaph said, try browsing to the URL manually through browser to see if controller actions work fine.

Comment: thanks. as what Zhaph said. I'll also take your idea about the url.